# Show that $\text{Cov}(\mu_X+X,\mu_Y+Y)=\text{Cov}(X,Y)$

Tags: covariance

I have a problem in my textbook:

Show that $\text{Cov}(\mu_X+X,\mu_Y+Y)=\text{Cov}(X,Y)$ for all deterministic $\mu_X,\mu_Y$ of the appropriate size.

My approach:

$$\text{Cov}(\mu_X+X,\mu_Y+Y)=\mathbb{E}\biggl[(\mu_X+X-\mathbb{E}[\mu_X+X])(\mu_Y+Y-\mathbb{E}[\mu_Y+Y])^T\biggr] = \mathbb{E}\biggl[(\mu_X+X-\mathbb{E}[X]- \mu_X)(\mu_Y+Y-\mathbb{E}[Y]-\mu_Y)^T\biggr]=\mathbb{E}\biggl[(X-\mathbb{E}[X])(Y-\mathbb{E}[Y])^T\biggr]=\text{Cov}(X,Y)$$

Would this approach be correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: @drhab thank you very much for reviewing my approach!:)